# jQuery - how to listen for the mouse leaving an area of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

In the application I'm working on, I use `span` tags in long paragraphs to provide both:

- A clickable link, handled with Javascript, and
- On mouseover, an "edit this" button displayed to the side of the link (with different functionality from the click).

Placing and showing the "edit this" button on mouseover is relatively easy. What I'm trying to figure out is, **how can I properly *hide* the button on mouseleave?**

See my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/6uKk8/4/

The problem:

- I can't just use the `mouseleave` event on the `span`, because that would hide the button before it can be clicked.
- I can't use a transparent `div` sized to include both the `span` and the button, because if the `div` is above the span, it blocks the `click` event, and if I use the `z-index` to place the `div` below the paragraph, it doesn't seem to receive the `mouseleave` event at all.

I could probably cludge something together with `mousemove` on the entire paragraph, but that seems really ugly. I don't think I can use some kind of coordinated event handling to check `mouseleave` on both the `span` and the `button`, because there's space between them.

My desired behavior is to have a (DOM-based or calculated) invisible box that includes both the `span` and the button, and to listen for the mouse leaving that box, at which time I can hide the button. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: You should use the .hover instead of the .mouseover in this case. That way you can specify one function to execute on mouseover and one on mouseleave very easily. Edit: oh nevermind, I see your problem, my point still stands though

Comment: @MarkKramer - yes, that would make sense if I was planning to trigger `mouseleave` from the same element - but as you can see, I'm not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put the hiding on a timer and start the timer when the mouse leaves your `<span>`:

```
var timer = null;
$('span.editable').mouseleave(function() {
    if(timer)
        clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#edit-this').hide();
        timer = null;
    }, 2000);
});
```

And then cancel the timer when the mouse enters `#edit-this` and set up a one-time event handler to hide `#edit-this` when the mouse leaves it:

```
$('#edit-this').mouseover(function() {
    if(timer)
        clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.one('mouseleave', function() {
        $this.hide();
    });
});
```

You'll also want to clear the timer in your `mouseover` for the span (thanks for catching this):

```
$('span.editable').mouseover(function(e) {
    if(timer)
        clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;
    // ...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pBtG8/2/

Comment: I like this solution, with a couple of changes - first, I think I can just attach `mouseleave` to `#edit-this` as a persistent handler in the normal fashion. Second, I need to deal with cross-span interactions - I can make the button disappear in your fiddle by going from span to span too quickly.

Comment: Huh, looking at the code, it should clear the old timeout on every new `mouseover`. I'm definitely seeing some disappearing buttons, though. I'll test further.

Comment: Ah, you have to clear the timer in the `$('span.editable').mouseover` handler as well. After that, this works great.

Comment: @nrabinowitz: Whether you use `one` or always have the handler around, I kind of like the way using `one` organizes the code and the logic flow. Sorry about missing the extra `clearTimeout`, I'll add that to the answer and fiddle for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is edit this to show until they mouseout of edit-this, this code will do the trick:

```
$('div.#edit-this').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#edit-this').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MarkKramer/6uKk8/12/

Also, I set it to use the jQuery timers plugin so when you scroll over, a timer will start and if the edit this button isn't scrolled over after two seconds, it will hide itself.

Comment: The problem is, I'd like the "edit this" button to go away when you stop hovering over *either* the editable `span` or the button. I don't want it hanging around when my mouse goes off somewhere else.

Comment: Oh, okay, sorry I was out for a while, but I'll fix that in a minute

Comment: Okay, fixed it. Now it uses the jqeury timers plugin to hide itself after two seconds unless you scroll over it.

Comment: Made one last fix, now the timer doesn't start until you mouseout of .editable